# Accessing Python Object Data

Tags: python, oop

I'm fairly new to python (and completely new to Python OO), but I'm working with a fairly complicated class that I'm struggling to understand but that I need to edit. To help understand what's going on I'm trying to pull data out of an object but everything I do is just returning "classname object at address".

Could someone explain to me how I'd go about printing, say, the vertex field in this object:

```
class Halfedge(object):
    def __init__(self, edge=None, marker=Edge.LEFT):
        self.left = None    # left Halfedge in the edge list
        self.right = None   # right Halfedge in the edge list
        self.qnext = None   # priority queue linked list pointer
        self.edge = edge    # edge list Edge
        self.marker = marker
        self.vertex = None  # Site()
        self.ystar = BIG_FLOAT

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.ystar == other.ystar and \
               self.vertex.x == other.vertex.x

    def __lt__(self, other):
        if self.ystar  == other.ystar:
            return self.vertex.x < other.vertex.x
        else:
            return self.ystar < other.ystar

    def left_reg(self, default):
        if not self.edge:
            return default
        elif self.marker == Edge.LEFT:
            return self.edge.reg[Edge.LEFT]
        else:
            return self.edge.reg[Edge.RIGHT]

    def right_reg(self, default):
        if not self.edge:
            return default
        elif self.marker == Edge.LEFT:
            return self.edge.reg[Edge.RIGHT]
        else:
            return self.edge.reg[Edge.LEFT]

    def is_point_right_of(self, point):
        """Returns True if <point> is to right of halfedge.
        """
        edge = self.edge
        topsite = edge.reg[1]
        right_of_site = point.x > topsite.x

        if(right_of_site and self.marker == Edge.LEFT):
            return True

        if(not right_of_site and self.marker == Edge.RIGHT):
            return False

        if(edge.a == 1.0):
            dyp = point.y - topsite.y
            dxp = point.x - topsite.x
            fast = 0
            if ((not right_of_site and edge.b < 0.0) or \
                (right_of_site and edge.b >= 0.0)):
                above = dyp >= edge.b * dxp
                fast = above
            else:
                above = point.x + point.y * edge.b > edge.c
                if(edge.b < 0.0):
                    above = not above
                if (not above):
                    fast = 1
            if (not fast):
                dxs = topsite.x - (edge.reg[0]).x
                above = (edge.b * (dxp*dxp - dyp*dyp)) < \
                        (dxs*dyp*(1.0+2.0*dxp/dxs + edge.b*edge.b))
                if(edge.b < 0.0):
                    above = not above
        else:  # edge.b == 1.0
            yl = edge.c - edge.a * point.x
            t1 = point.y - yl
            t2 = point.x - topsite.x
            t3 = yl - topsite.y
            above = t1*t1 > t2*t2 + t3*t3

        if(self.marker == Edge.LEFT):
            return above
        else:
            return not above

    def intersect(self, other):
        """Create a new site where the Halfedges edge1 and edge2 intersect.
        """
        edge1 = self.edge
        edge2 = other.edge
        if (edge1 is None) or (edge2 is None):
            return None

        # if the two edges bisect the same parent return None
        if edge1.reg[1] is edge2.reg[1]:
            return None

        d = edge1.a * edge2.b - edge1.b * edge2.a
        if almost_equal(d, 0.0):
            return None

        intersect_x = (edge1.c * edge2.b - edge2.c * edge1.b) / d
        intersect_y = (edge2.c * edge1.a - edge1.c * edge2.a) / d
        if edge1.reg[1] < edge2.reg[1]:
            halfedge = self
            edge = edge1
        else:
            halfedge = other
            edge = edge2

        right_of_site = intersect_x >= edge.reg[1].x
        if ((right_of_site and halfedge.marker == Edge.LEFT) or
            (not right_of_site and halfedge.marker == Edge.RIGHT)):
            return None

        # create a new site at the point of intersection - this is a new
        # vector event waiting to happen
        return Site((intersect_x, intersect_y))
```

I know this is pretty simple stuff, but thanks for any help.

Edit: The entire class I'm using can be found at:

https://bitbucket.org/mozman/geoalg/src/5bbd46fa2270/geoalg/voronoi.py

Comment: So, what have you tried so far?

Comment: also, what "vector variable"? There is only a "vertex" *field* (not "variable").

Comment: Sorry, typo, it's the vertex field I want returned. If I understand correctly, it should return, or be a pointer to, a ooordinate. I'll edit the main post so it links to the entire class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have a Halfedge instance - let's call it `my_halfedge` - you access any of its properties with the dot notation. So, for the `vertex` property, you'd do `my_halfedge.vertex`.

Comment: Hmm, I tried that out using the bisector one that the class creates. It returns "voronoi.Site object at address". Would I then have to find the attribute inside the Site object to add onto the end of the print statement?

Comment: To find the attributes of the object, you can do `dir(my_halfedge.vertex)` - then just add the attribute after another dot, for instance `my_halfedge.vertex.my_attribute`.

Comment: Ah, that seems to have done the trick. Thanks a lot. Despite spending a reasonable amount of time with python I've somehow managed to completely avoid object oriented programming in it.

Answer (score 1):

To make an instance of Halfedge do, for example,

```
he2 = Halfedge()
```

and to print this instance's value of vertex do

```
print he2.vertex
```

Is this what you're after?